# How to extend `==` behavior to vectors that include NAs?

Tags: r

I've completely failed at searching for other r-help or Stack Overflow discussion of this specific issue. Sorry if it's somewhere obvious. I believe that I'm just looking for the easiest way to get R's == sign to never return NAs.

```
# Example #

# Say I have two vectors
a <- c( 1 , 2 , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
# And want to test if each element in the first
# is identical to each element in the second:
a == b
# It does what I want perfectly:
# TRUE TRUE FALSE

# But if either vector contains a missing,
# the `==` operator returns an incorrect result:
a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
b <- c( 1 , NA , 4 )
# Here I'd want   TRUE TRUE FALSE
a == b
# But I get TRUE NA FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
# Here I'd want   TRUE FALSE FALSE
a == b
# But I get TRUE NA FALSE again.
```

I get the result I want with:

```
mapply( `%in%` , a , b )
```

But `mapply` seems heavy-handed to me.

Is there a more intuitive solution to this?

Comment: The help file (`?"=="`) seems pretty firm about this: `Missing values (NA) and NaN values are regarded as non-comparable even to themselves, so comparisons involving them will always result in NA` - but someone else might have a better answer for you.

Comment: @nrussell yep, i understand `==` isn't the solution here.  i only mention it because its default behavior is _pretty close_ to what i want. :)

Comment: If you consider replacing the NA with 0 or something, `replace(a, is.na(a), 0)==replace(b, is.na(b), 0)`

Comment: @akrun: `Inf` might be a better choice.

Comment: `ifelse(is.na(a),is.na(b),a==b)`

Comment: @A.Webb I think ifelse would be slower than `replace`

Comment: @akrun, don't they both have complexity O(n)?

Comment: @A.Webb you win the most intuitive award

Comment: @A.Webb that does not guarantee that `(a %==% b) == (b %==% a)`

Comment: @rawr A counterexample would be helpful.

Comment: @A.Webb sure, well just switch a and b the last example in the question, `ifelse` gives true/na/false instead of true/false/false

Comment: Thanks, this would need to be `ifelse(is.na(a) | is.na(b),is.na(b) & is.na(b) ,a==b)` instead.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Another option, but is it better than `mapply('%in%', a , b)`?:

```
(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))
```

**Following @AnthonyDamico 's suggestion, creation of the "mutt" operator:**

```
"%==%" <- function(a, b) (!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))
```

**Edit: or, slightly different and shorter version by @Frank (which is also more efficient)**

```
"%==%" <- function(a, b) (is.na(a) & is.na(b)) | (!is.na(eq <- a==b) & eq)
```

***With the different examples:***

```
a <- c( 1 , 2 , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
a %==% b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , NA , 4 )
a %==% b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
a %==% b
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 )
b <- c( 3 , NA , 1 )
a %==% b
#[1] FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: we should call it the mutt operator because it's sort of equalsequals and sort of `%in%` and then we can define it so it looks like a dog bone.  `%==% <- function( a , b ) (!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))`

Comment: A somewhat shorter function: `f = function(a, b) (is.na(a) & is.na(b)) | ( !is.na(eq <- a == b) & eq )` since `!is.na(a==b)` implies `!is.na(a) & !is.na(b)`

Comment: @Frank that's smart ! - added the option to the solution

Answer (score 13):

You could try

```
replace(a, is.na(a), Inf)==replace(b, is.na(b), Inf)
```

Or a faster variation suggested by @docendo discimus

```
replace(a, which(is.na(a)), Inf)==replace(b, which(is.na(b)), Inf)
```

Based on the different scenarios

1.

```
a <- c( 1 , 2 , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
akrun1()
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

2.

```
 a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
 b <- c( 1 , NA , 4 )
 akrun1()
 #[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

3.

```
 a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
 b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
 akrun1()
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

#### Benchmarks

```
set.seed(24)
a <- sample(c(1:10, NA), 1e6, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(c(1:20, NA), 1e6, replace=TRUE)
akrun1 <- function() {replace(a, is.na(a), Inf)==replace(b, is.na(b), Inf)}
cathG <- function() {(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))}
anthony <- function() {mapply(`%in%`, a, b)}
webb <- function() {ifelse(is.na(a),is.na(b),a==b)}
docend <- function() {replace(a, which(is.na(a)), Inf)==replace(b,
       which(is.na(b)), Inf)}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(akrun1(), cathG(), anthony(), webb(),docend(),
  unit='relative', times=20L)
#Unit: relative
#    expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max
#  akrun1()   3.050200   3.035625   3.007196   2.963916   2.977490   3.083658
#   cathG()   4.829972   4.893266   4.843585   4.790466   4.816472   4.939316
# anthony() 190.499027 224.389971 215.792965 217.647702 215.503308 212.356051
#    webb()  14.000363  14.366572  15.412527  14.095947  14.671741  19.735746
#  docend()   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000   1.000000
# neval cld
#    20 a  
#    20 a  
#    20 c
#    20 b 
#    20 a
```

Comment: I can see why you're replacing by `Inf` instead of `0` but couldn't any value also be `Inf` and you'll get `TRUE` when comparing `NA` to `Inf` ? (ok, it will probably never happen, it was just to talk... Thanks for benchmarking and I like my solution's results ;-) )

Comment: this is amazing, thank you!  i think i like @CathG's solution the best, since it doesn't require any safeword value - in your solution, infinities aren't allowed.  but it's nice to know yours is 33% faster (or is that 50%?)

Comment: @CathG Looks like I need to replace it by something that cannot possibly occur in a dataset :-)

Comment: `akrun2 <- function() {replace(a, which(is.na(a)), Inf)==replace(b, which(is.na(b)), Inf)}` is more than 3 times faster than `akrun1()` on my machine.

Comment: @docendodiscimus Thanks, I will include it.

Comment: It surprises me, I'd have expected `which` to be called anyway down the line when providing boolean indices. Is it good practice to wrap boolean indices inside `which` calls  in general to improve performance ?

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper  It depends on the number of NA elements in the column/vector.  Check these `set.seed(24);
v1 <- sample(c(NA, 1), 1e7, replace = TRUE);set.seed(42);
v2 <- sample(c(NA, 1:1000), 1e7, replace = TRUE)` and then by running `system.time(is.na(v1))#
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.03    0.00    0.03 

system.time(which(is.na(v1)))
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.08    0.06    0.14; system.time(is.na(v2))
# user  system elapsed 
#   0.00    0.01    0.02 
system.time(which(is.na(v2)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.00    0.02    0.01`

Comment: I see thanks, the overhead cost of the `which` call is offset by the fact you're copying a smaller object, IF the object is much smaller.

Comment: `Inf` can be replaced by `.Machine$double.xmax` at a minor cost, and with much less chances of undesired side effects as I can't think of a realistic usecase of `.Machine$double.xmax` in a vector.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that we don't have a big relative number of `NA`, The proposed vectorized solution waste some ressources comparing values that have already been settled by `a==b`.

We can usually assume that `NAs` are few so it makes it worth computing `a==b` first and then deal with the `NAs` separately, despite the additional steps and temp variables:

```
`%==%` <- function(a,b){
  x <- a==b
  na_x <- which(is.na(x))
  x[na_x] <- is.na(a[na_x]) & is.na(b[na_x])
  x
}
```

**Check output**

```
a <- c( 1 , 2 , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
a %==% b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
b <- c( 1 , NA , 4 )
a %==% b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
a %==% b
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

**Benchmarks**

I'm reproducing below @akrun's benchmark with fastest solutions only and n=100.

```
set.seed(24)
a <- sample(c(1:10, NA), 1e6, replace=TRUE)
b <- sample(c(1:20, NA), 1e6, replace=TRUE)
mm <- function(){
  x <- a==b
  na_x <- which(is.na(x))
  x[na_x] <- is.na(a[na_x]) & is.na(b[na_x])
  x
}
akrun1 <- function() {replace(a, is.na(a), Inf)==replace(b, is.na(b), Inf)}
cathG <- function() {(!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))}
docend <- function() {replace(a, which(is.na(a)), Inf)==replace(b, which(is.na(b)), Inf)}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mm(),akrun1(),cathG(),docend(),
               unit='relative', times=100L)

# Unit: relative
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#     mm() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000   100
# akrun1() 1.667242 1.884185 1.815392 1.642581 1.765238 0.9973017   100
#  cathG() 2.447168 2.449597 2.118306 2.201346 2.358105 1.1421577   100
# docend() 1.683817 1.950970 1.756481 1.745400 2.007889 1.2264461   100
```

**Extending `==`**

As the original question is really to find :

> the easiest way to get `R`'s `==` sign to never return `NAs`

Here's a way, where we define a new class `na_comparable`. Only one of the vector needs to be of this class as the other will be coerced to it.

```
na_comparable      <- setClass("na_comparable", contains = "numeric")
`==.na_comparable` <- function(a,b){
  x <- unclass(a) == unclass(b) # inefficient but I don't know how to force the default `==`
  na_x <- which(is.na(x))
  x[na_x] <- is.na(a[na_x]) & is.na(b[na_x])
  x
}

`!=.na_comparable` <- Negate(`==.na_comparable`)

a <- na_comparable(a)
a == b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
b == a
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
a != b
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
b != a
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

In a dplyr chain it could be conveniently used this way :

```
data.frame(a=c(1,NA,3),b=c(1,NA,4)) %>%
  mutate(a = na_comparable(a),
         c = a==b,
         d= a!=b)

#    a  b     c     d
# 1  1  1  TRUE FALSE
# 2 NA NA  TRUE FALSE
# 3  3  4 FALSE  TRUE
```

With this approach, in case you need to update code to account for `NAs` that were absent before, you might be set with a single `na_comparable` call instead of transforming your initial data or replacing all your `==` with `%==%` down the line.

Answer (score 4):

How about using `identical()` wrapped in `mapply()`

```
a <- c( 1 , 2 , 3 )
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
mapply(identical,a,b)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
b <- c( 1 , NA , 4 )
mapply(identical,a,b)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a <- c( 1 , NA , 3 ) 
b <- c( 1 , 2 , 4 )
mapply(identical,a,b)
#[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE
```

Also, if you need to compare results from calculations you could get rid of `identical()` and go with `isTRUE(all.equal())` like so

```
mapply(FUN=function(x,y){isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))}, a, b)
```

which gives the same outcomes, but can better deal with rounding issues.
 Such as

```
a<-.3/3
b<-.1
mapply(FUN=function(x,y){isTRUE(all.equal(x,y))}, a, b)
#[1] TRUE

mapply(identical,a,b)
#[1] FALSE
```

I think this last example would mess up a lot of the proposed solutions - but switching to `all.equal` instead of `==` would likely work for all of them.