# Comparnig NAs in two different data sets

Tags: r, na

I am comparing values from two datasets.  Often I want to know if the values are equal. Sometimes both values are `NA`.

As you may know `NA == NA` returns `NA`.
I wish it returned `TRUE`.

As you may know `NA == 10` returns `NA`.
I wish it returned `FALSE`.

A couple options I've considered:

1. Check if the first value `is.na` then check if the second value `is.na`
2. `mutate_all` the `NA` values in both data sets to an empty character.

Is there any other clever way of dealing with this that I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `identical` function returns only `TRUE` or `FALSE`, no type coercion, no vectorization :

```
identical(NA,NA)     # TRUE
identical(1,1)       # TRUE    
identical(1:2,1:2)   # TRUE   
identical(c(a=1,b=2),1:2) # FALSE
identical(1,1L)      # FALSE
identical(NA_integer_,NA_character_) # FALSE
identical(NULL,NULL) # TRUE
identical(NULL,NA)   # FALSE
```

`%in%` can be used as a trick but for example `NULL %in% NA` returns `logical(0)`

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238467/how-to-extend-behavior-to-vectors-that-include-nas/49375415#49375415) is about an operator `%==%` that would support `NA` equality.

See also `?all.equal`, `all.equal(NA,NA)` returns `TRUE` (but `all.equal(NA,1)` doesn't return `FALSE` !)

*That being said*

If you want `NA == NA` to be `TRUE`, it means that you believe `NA` is a meaningful value in itself. If you do believe this, it's perfectly acceptable (and probably better) that you set your NAs to an explicit value, even if it's the empty string, `0` , `"other"` or `"unknown"`.

`NA == NA` is `NA` because when you don't know what is on the lhs and what is on the rhs, you don't know if they're equal. If you know, it means they're not `NAs`.

indirectly related: see `?isTRUE` that will be `FALSE` for everything that is not `TRUE`

```
isTRUE(c(TRUE,TRUE)) # FALSE (not a length 1 `TRUE` logical)
```

**Edit to answer comments:**

I understand NA as "not available" (i.e. missing), not "not applicable" which is a category. `?NA` agrees:

> ‘Not Available’ / Missing Values

If I have an unknown apartment number in dataset A I would be careful before doing a left join to dataset B, because the apartment number might be known on B's side, and then won't match,or they'll be another apartment with a missing number, and i'll match things that don't belong together.

If I'm matching a house however, I can for example set the number to 0 as a convention for "not applicable" for all houses in both of my datasets and then i can safely join, or safely remove real `NAs`.

What would you do with the following datasets if you lost the `id` column ? :

```
A <- data.frame(
  id = 1:5,
  place = c("house1","building1","buiding1","buiding1","building2"),
  apartment_number = c(NA, 1, NA,3,1),
  has_dog = c(T, T, T, F,F))

B <- data.frame(
  id=1:5,
  place = c("house1","building1","buiding1","buiding1","building2"),
  apartment_number = c(NA, 1,2, NA,1),
  has_cat = c(T, T, T, F, F))

# A                                        # B
#   id     place apartment_number has_dog  #   id     place apartment_number has_cat
# 1  1    house1               NA    TRUE  # 1  1    house1               NA    TRUE
# 2  2 building1                1    TRUE  # 2  2 building1                1    TRUE
# 3  3  buiding1               NA    TRUE  # 3  3  buiding1                2    TRUE
# 4  4  buiding1                3   FALSE  # 4  4  buiding1               NA   FALSE
# 5  5 building2                1   FALSE  # 5  5 building2                1   FALSE
```

A naive merge:

```
merge(A[-1],B[-1])
#       place apartment_number has_dog has_cat
# 1  buiding1               NA    TRUE   FALSE  # TRUE/FALSE ???
# 2 building1                1    TRUE    TRUE
# 3 building2                1   FALSE   FALSE
# 4    house1               NA    TRUE    TRUE
```

In my data everyone who has a cat also has also a dog, and now I messed up my pet predictor model!

An option would be to do a full join to keep all available apartment numbers (and create NAs in has_dog and has_cat columns), then remove the rows with `apartment_number == NAs`, but of course keep I want to keep the houses, so I should set these `NAs` to 0 the sooner the cleaner.

Comment: You bring up an interesting question about the meaning of `NA`. But let's look at address data. Some people have an apartment number, others don't. So, the column APT_NUM is `NA` for those that don't. It's not that we "don't know" what their apt number is, it's just that that field is **not applicable** for that record.

Comment: It's not always clear cut and my opinion might not be shared by all, but in the case of an apartment number I believe I will persist and sign, see my answer for an example

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is `%in%`

```
NA %in% NA   #TRUE
NA %in% 10   #FALSE
```

Comment: thanks. such strange syntax. I've only ever used that for `1 %in% c(1,2,3)`

Comment: jap its a special thing. Read more [HERE](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/r-in-a/9781449358204/ch06s02.html)