# data.table with extended `==` function not working in R

Tags: r, data.table, na, logical-operators

This is a follow-up question below.

[How to extend `==` behavior to vectors that include NAs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28238467/how-to-extend-behavior-to-vectors-that-include-nas)

In the link, suppose we would like to compare

```
a = c(1,2,NA)
b = c(1,3,NA)
```

Using the function of `"%==%" <- function(a, b) (!is.na(a) & !is.na(b) & a==b) | (is.na(a) & is.na(b))`, and we have the following result

```
a %==% b
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

My question is how to use `%==%` in the `data.table::data.table` function. Why the following code does not work properly? The first two results are good, but it seems that `%==%` cannot be used with operations, i.e. the `a+a2` below.

```
dt_a = data.table(a = a, a2 = a+a)
dt_a[,a %==% b] 
# TRUE FALSE  TRUE
dt_a[,a2 %==% b]
# FALSE FALSE  TRUE
dt_a[,a+a2 %==% b]
# 1  2 NA # this line of result is confusing.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a problem of operator precedence. You would need

```
dt_a[,(a+a2) %==% b]
```

The fake equals has a different precedence than a normal `==` what you write originally was equivalent to

```
dt_a[,a+(a2 %==% b)]
```

Addition operators are higher precedence than test for equality but lower precedence than custom infix `%%` functions. See the `?Syntax` help page for the full details.

Note this doesn't have anything to do with `data.table` specifically. Same things happens outside

```
a <- c(1,2,NA)
b <- c(1,3,NA)
a2 <- a+ a
a+a2 %==% b
# [1]  1  2 NA
```

Comment: Good catch! Is it possible to edit directly in the function, so that `a + a2 %==% b` returns `FALSE FALSE  TRUE`?

Comment: No. you cannot change the operator precedence for `%%` functions.  You could give the function a different name and call it like `myequal(a+a2, b)` or something like that. But you can't fundamentally change the R parser. All that logic happens in C code.